# play framework WS API always escape character ';' and '=' in URL

Tags: api, url, playframework, escaping, playframework-2.1

When I send a URL like abc.efg.com/query?para1=cat;para2=dog, play WS API always convert it to abc.efg.com/query?para1=cat%03Bpara2%03Ddog. Of course, there are http:// in the beginning in the URL. my code is as below.
    val url= "http://abc.efg.com/query?para1=cat;para2=dog"
    val response = WS.url(url).get()

When I use fidder or netmon to look at the data that sent to sever, I found play framework WS (2.1.5) always change to the URL above I mentioned. How do I tell WS not to convert?

Answer (score 1):

The semicolon is an alternate syntax to ampersand (&) as a seperator for query parameters, so it must be encoded.

If you want multiple query parameters, you should use `withQueryString`.